# R attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to run this code but i'm getting this error:

**Error in rep(x[[i]], n) :
attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'**

Please help to solve this and tell me what exactly i need to change/add to my code

```r
monthyear = c('January 2015', 'February 2015', 'March 2016', 
              'April 2016', 'May 2016', 'June 2016', 'July 2016', 
              'January 2017', 'Februrary 2017', 
              'August 2017', 'September 2017', 'October 2017')

c_report = c(742, 3420, 4263, 5147, 6255, 93872, 2323, 
             4677, 9398, 2112, 1000, 7890)

o_report = c(30185, 33894, 33642, 29439, 27879 ,52347, 
             4578, 3639, 10000, 48781, 64484, 5020)

data.m <- melt(df, id.vars='dateyear')

ggplot(data.m, aes(dateyear, c_report)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = o_report), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

thank you

Comment: Where does the variable `df` come from? It helps if your errors are reproducible to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
monthyear = c('January 2015', 'February 2015', 'March 2016', 
              'April 2016', 'May 2016', 'June 2016', 'July 2016', 
              'January 2017', 'Februrary 2017', 
              'August 2017', 'September 2017', 'October 2017')

c_report = c(742, 3420, 4263, 5147, 6255, 93872, 2323, 
             4677, 9398, 2112, 1000, 7890)

o_report = c(30185, 33894, 33642, 29439, 27879 ,52347, 
             4578, 3639, 10000, 48781, 64484, 5020)

library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(monthyear, c_report, o_report) %>% 
  mutate(dateyear = gsub("[A-Za-z ]", "", monthyear)) %>% 
  select(-monthyear) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-dateyear)

ggplot(df, aes(dateyear, value)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = name), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: This answer could be improved by an explanation of how and why this solves the error.